# "Cannot read property 'dialogService' of undefined" Angular 9 gapi function

Tags: angular, angular8, google-api-js-client, nebular

I'm trying to open a dialog box with data retrieved from google API client (`gapi`). Everything works just fine until I try to load the data into a dialog box. I'm receiving the data fine and I can pass data into the dialog box in other functions fine with no issues, but for some reason I can't do it within the `gapi` function.

I'm using NbDialog from Nebular within an Angular framework. Here's my code:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FileListComponent } from '../../../pages/modal-overlays/dialog/file-list/file-list.component';
import { NbDialogService } from '@nebular/theme';

const gapi: any

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-header',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
})


export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 
 constructor(private dialogService: NbDialogService){}
 
 ngOnInit(){

    //Initialize

    gapi.load("client:auth2", () =>{
      gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        discoveryDocs: ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest'],
        clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        scope: 'profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
      }).then(function () {
        // Listen for sign-in state changes.
        // gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);
        // Handle the initial sign-in state.
        if(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get()){
          console.log('Sign-in successful');
          gapi.client.drive.files.list({
            pageSize: 100,
            corpora:'allDrives',
            fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name)",
            includeItemsFromAllDrives:true,
            supportsAllDrives:true,
            q:"mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.document'",
          }).then(function(res) {

            // console.log returns data perfectly fine

            console.log(res.result)
                 
             // below returns "Cannot read property 'dialogService' of undefined" even though I've used the
             // EXACT same function outside this one with no issues                
 
            this.dialogService.open(FileListComponent, {
              context: {
                list: res.result.files,
              },

            });
          });
        }
        else{
          console.log('there was an error with sign-in my friend')
        }

      });

    })
  }
```

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: There are syntax errors in your snippet, can you fix those? Also dialogService should be a parameter of the constructor, not supposed to be inside it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I can't seem to find any errors other than the one you mentioned and that `gapi` wasn't declared. Would you mind listing anything else? It may just be the issue.

Comment: Replace all `.then(function () {` with `.then(() => {`

Comment: Thanks yurzui! That was it!